# What does "excluded" mean on the CBP airport wait times report?

Tags: usa, borders

I can't imagine what this could be. It seems too low for GE/Nexus and way too high for refused entry. What is it...?

[image: CBP airport wait times]

Comment: I wouldn't think it's unusual for refusals to arrive in bunches - possibly certain departure points are more likely to produce them...

Comment: According to the "definitions" link at the top of the page: "The actual number of passengers on flights which arrived in the selected hour who were excluded from wait time reporting." Not particularly helpful I realize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [definitions page](http://awt.cbp.gov/Specs.aspx):

> **Excluded:** The actual number of passengers on flights which arrived in the selected hour who were excluded from wait time reporting.

That sounds like passengers who were allowed entry but did not need processing time, for example infants who have no passports and share the same passport with their moms. If they were counted among the processed passengers then the report would not be accurate because only one person was passport/person was processed in reality. Just a guess.

One more thing, I do not think they are passengers who were refused entry, because even they need "processing" time and can not be excluded from the waiting time report.

Comment: Where have you found the link to definitions?? I was looking but couldn't find it.

Comment: top-right corner, thanks to Zach Liption he commented about it first.

Comment: Can children still be included on parents' passports?  I thought that was no longer allowed, but maybe it's only for the VWP?  In any event, another reason for excluding passengers might be related to fast-track immigration services for VIPs such as diplomats whose immigration paperwork is handled by their staff.

Comment: @phoog good point, I guess VIPs are included, but not the only ones, if you check the page you will see that the number of excluded people are too high to be only for VIPs. Regarding VWP, they still need to visit a booth before entering.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis there's at least one service that advertises that they'll take care of the immigration formalities while you wait in a lounge.  I find that surprising, but there it is. Four VIPs could be a single family or a government delegation.  Since the data sample shows only one aircraft, it's possible that it's not a representative sample.

Comment: @phoog I have actually checked other days with many flights, the excluded number was too high in some cases for VIPs only.. check it yourself and see.

Comment: @HedelBerGensis federal air marshals? Or maybe it's people who clear the border with a passport other than the one listed on the manifest, so they can't match the arriving passenger record with a processing record.

Comment: @phoog I initially thought they might be crew, but then the number of the excluded people and the number of the flights do not make sense, smae thing goes for airmarshals, what sort of a flight that has 130 passengers are 4 of them are airmarshals? plus, airmarshals are not provided in in all flights for all countries, I know of Saudi Arabia, Egypt and the US only.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis of course they're not all air marshals, but it's possible that the people are excluded for various reasons, and one of them might be an air marshal.

Comment: @phoog Crew, including marshals, actually pass through the booths when going to the US, at least for foreign airlines, I have done that myself when going to the US as a crew member.

Comment: I know crew do, but wouldn't an air marshal going to the crew line blow his cover? I am favoring the unmatched record hypothesis at the moment.